# Prevent delay image display

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to create an effect with mouseover on certain elements on the page. Each element has a "normal" **background** image, Upon mouseover, the image changes and a new background image is loaded.  Mouse out, and the normal background image is restored.   Obviously, I could do the same thing with CSS. But because of other considerations (e.g., the element that I'm using to trigger and the other effects on the page, jQuery is a far easier tool).

The problem is; when the event is triggered, there is a "flash" - really, a pause while the image loads. Interestingly, if I mouse out and mouse back in, there is no hesitation. The lag is cause when there is mouse over and out on one element, then mouse in on anther.

Any way to obvious way to mitigate this problem?

Code used follows:

```js
      $(function() {
        $(".panel3-sub-button-text > p").hoverIntent(swapInFPP3Text, swapOutFPP3Text, function(){}); 
      });
      
      function swapInFPP3Text(evt) {
  
        // Get the class of the bubble
        $bubble_class = $(this).attr('id');
 
        
        //Swap in the appropriate text for the bubble hovered over
        if ($bubble_class == 'math-bubble-text' ) {
          console.log('>>> Fire rules for: ', $bubble_class);
          $('#panel3-default-text').addClass("hidden");
          $('#panel3-math-text').removeClass("hidden");
          $('#panel3-epidemiology-text').addClass("hidden");
          $('#panel3-hiv-text').addClass("hidden");
          $('#panel3-malari-text').addClass("hidden");
          $('#panel3-polio-text').addClass("hidden");
          $('#panel3-tuberculosis-text').addClass("hidden");
          $('div#math-bubble').css('background-image','url("/sites/default/files/fp_math_bubble_hover.png")');
          $('p#math-bubble-text').css('color','rgb(216, 216, 216)');

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your images are taking some time to load. Try compressing the images. That is the only solution. If it is slow even after compressing, replace those images with some other images having smaller size.

**EDIT**

Another thing is, take a look at

```
  $('div#math-bubble').css('background-image','url("/sites/default/files/fp_math_bubble_hover.png")');
```

You are loading the image dynamically using jquery. What you can do is put this background image into a class, hide it and show it once the user hovers over. So, the image is loaded before the user hovers over the content.

Comment: Images are already compressed and very small (e.g., 4KB). 

There must be another solution - perhaps using the .animate method?

Comment: Then try preloading the images as epascarello said. See my edit @user908998

Answer (score 0):

Try to preload hover images (put this to the body onload or ready):

```
var preloaded_image = new Image();
preloaded_image.src = '/sites/default/files/fp_math_bubble_hover.png';
```